# Align left multi category xaxis highchart

Tags: highcharts, alignment, axis, categories

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

I want to **align left** the **label** but when i do this, the label a stack on other like **Image 2**.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set useHTML as true, use formatter for labels and then use CSS styles.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.useHTML
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QREQ/3/

```
xAxis: {

            labels: {
                //align: 'center'
                useHTML:true,
                formatter:function(){

                    return '<div class="label">'+this.value+'</div>';
                }
            }
        },
```

CSS

```
.label {
text-align:left;
width:60px;
```

}

Comment: thank for your help. I can do it now. But my category text is longer than 60px, i want to set it width as auto. But when i set auto, it does align right again :(

Comment: If you set width as auto, then you cannot use text-align, cause object (label) has width of text, not "block". So you should define width as i.e 100 or bigger, which will be correct for length of your words.

Answer (score 3):

This one works without fixed width:

```
.highcharts-axis-labels span {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Since it uses the width of the biggest label and moves the smaller once by raising the "left" value, you can prevent that by setting it fix to 0. So no need of fix width or "align: left".

Update:

Labels "useHTML" setting must be set to true to work!

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    useHTML: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the green and the blue bar a container div/span. Then apply for both of the label and the container span/div a 'display: inline-block' css.

By doing so you would force the bars to 'give space' for the label.

Comment: The label a stack on other, not the chart stack on label.