# Highcharts: wrong labels align for inverted charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, alignment

To align x-axis labels of an inverted chart, default should be 'center', but it looks like it's right. And if we force `align='center'`, we get a display bug.

```
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            align: 'center'
        },
    },
```

Chek this http://jsfiddle.net/dnvZj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is related with this: [Align left multi category xaxis highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473478/align-left-multi-category-xaxis-highchart)

http://jsfiddle.net/2QREQ/4/

```
labels: {
                //align: 'center'
                useHTML:true,
                formatter:function(){

                    return '<div class="label">'+this.value+'</div>';
                }
            },
```

CSS:

```
.label {
text-align:center;
width:60px;
```

}